# Move login form from subdomain to homepage and sort comapanies alphabetically

Tags: cakephp

Outsourced a document management system to a CakePHP developer who has now disappeared, without doing the final touches, leaving me high and dry. Project is due Monday the 28th, I'm freaking! I sat for 2 days, but couldn't solve these issues. The main thing is the member login form at dms.domain.com.

It works perfectly and redirects to http://dms.domain.com/dir/dir but members actually need to log in via the login form I created on the homepage www.domain.com

I had a look at the source of the login form on the dms.domain.com which looks really simple, much like standard  code, however I tried searching for the form elements in the source code of the entire site, but no luck. This leads me to believe that everything's called from the database, but hopefully not because that's out of my league.

Surely if I can find the form code used on dms.domain.com I can just reuse it on the home page?

The second thing is, once logged in, the list of companies is sorted via date created it seems? but I want it sorted via company, alphabetically. Again I searched the source for code like "asc" but I realized Cake doesn't use standard sql queries. I did however find, 'sortorder' => 'desc', 'sortname' => 'id', and changed 'id' to 'company' but no luck. Below is what I currently see when log in. Thanks

Id Company

1 Fos

21 Mamas

20 Clove

25 Orm

24 Colors

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your main site `www.domain.com` is not written using CakePHP - is that right? If that's the case, you could just copy the generated HTML of the login form on `dms.domain.com` and paste it into the login form on `www.domain.com`. Make sure that the `action` of the form is set to the full path to the login action on `dms.domain.com` e.g. `http://dms.domain.com/dir/dir`.